# Detection of a paste event originated from the default ContextMenu in a flash TextField

Tags: flash, actionscript, contextmenu, textfield, paste

Textfields currently do not dispatch paste events. 
When the user is using keyboard shortcuts to paste, there's a way to workaround that shortcoming by listening to various keyboard events in the textfield.

Is there a way to detect the paste event when it is originated from a click on the ContextMenu?

Answer (score 0):

When you choose an item in a `ContextMenu`, the chosen `ContextMenuItem` dispatches a [**menuItemSelect**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenuItem.html#event%3amenuItemSelect) event. Use that.

Comment: I just can't get a reference of the default contextMenu in order to add an event listener. I've tried a lot. Would you be so kind and provide a working example?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking now. Can't you just listen for the `paste` event in the TextInput? According to Adobe, it is: *Dispatched when the user activates the platform specific accelerator key combination for a paste operation or selects 'Paste' from the text context menu.*

Comment: Unfortunately pasting text with the use of the ContextMenu of a textField does not generate any events. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html?filter_osmf=1&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5#contextMenu

Comment: Hmm ... I just tested it and you're right. The docs say it should, and the code completion on the TextInput in MXML even offers "paste" as a valid event to listen for. But the handler doesn't get called. Bummer.

Comment: what kind of screw up system is this?.....I've been searching for days now for any way to detect paste events into a textField, did you figure it out fusion?

Comment: No I haven't. You might be able to workaround this by looking at the selection property before and after the text change. I think i must have done it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Write this :

```
this.stage.addEventListener( Event.PASTE, handlePaste );
```

and then when you click on "paste" in the ContextMenu of flash player, the `handlePaste` is called